# Python 3.7 , 3.8 any version I have used of python pandas datareader and get_data_yahoo problems, current date goes back 5 days after a few minutes

Tags: python-3.x, yahoo-finance, pandas-datareader

While using my python script that uses pandas-DataReader v10 & pandas v1.3.3 get_data_yahoo(), when it first starts off it will show the last 5 days correctly because I am tailing this for the last 5 days, then after about a minute or two it changes to what you see below, I am using python 3.7.10 The date moves back 2 weeks and the volume from the last 4 days is off  a lot, the current day is always correct ok

```
-----------------------------------------
def get_data(tickers):
        df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(tickers)
        return df

for df in tickers:
            df = get_data(df)     # this function retrieve's stock information from yahoo finance 
            df = pd.DataFrame(df.Close)
        print(df.tail(5)
--------------------------------------------
```

```
#1 --- works correctly
              Close  
Date
2021-08-15  11.2500   
2021-09-16   9.9600          
2021-09-17  11.0600         
2021-09-20  11.7300          
2021-09-21  13.7001

#2 --- doesn't work correctly
              Close  
Date
2021-08-31   5.9600  
2021-09-01   7.4000          
2021-09-02   6.4900         
2021-09-03   6.7000          
2021-09-21  13.7001
```

Comment: Your "works correctly" output shows a jump of a month, from `2021-08-15` to `2021-06-16`. That makes it very hard to guess what the issue you're actually describing is. Does the rest of the dataframe make sense? You're only looking at the `tail` here, but are the other data points present, if out of order?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, tail() shows data that is in last location, and data displayed on screen can vary. If you want to validate data, sort & compare by Date.

```
 print(df.sort_values('Date').tail(5))
```

Comment: The tail() function works correctly but the date changes after about 5 or 6 minutes from the previoius day and back it's almost as if something is being cached but I checked for that. and the volume information goes into the billions when it is only in the millions